# how to use new set in react with a async Data in react

Tags: reactjs

new Set is a really cool feature to create an array or abject of unique value, but it not working when I want to apply it on my async data assuming that data is stored in my state :

```
const [levels, setLevels] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=> {
    const GetCoursesYoga = async () => {
      const result = await GetCourses();
      setYogaCourses(result);
      setLevels(new Set(result.map((result)=> result.level)));
      console.log(result);
    } 
    GetCoursesYoga();
  }, []);
```

new Set is not working the way I want it? what do you think guys?

Comment: I am not so sure about some of the variable but I think you can essentially do as : https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-cdn-vg7kh

Comment: What's not working about it? Show us what you're getting and what you want to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create an array from the `new Set`

```js
const [levels, setLevels] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=> {
    const GetCoursesYoga = async () => {
      const result = await GetCourses();
      setYogaCourses(result);
      setLevels(Array.from(new Set(result.map((result)=> result.level))));
      console.log(result);
    } 
    GetCoursesYoga();
  }, []);
```

Let me know if it solves the problem

Comment: it solves the problem Hicham thank you so much

Comment: What would be your advice for someone newbie to be good at solving problems?

Comment: I don't understand your question sorry. What you mean by `someone new` ?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say what would be your 3 advices for a person who is a beginner to be good at solving problems in javascript or React?

Comment: 1-Practice...2-Practice...and ...3-Practice 

Comment: Hahaha I know, but precisely what kind of resources do you use to get better everyday at solving problems :D

Comment: For pure javascript and algorithm, the clash of code from CodinGame helped me a lot. For React, working on side projects and follow tutorials and read documentations helped me :)

Comment: Thank you so much Man that was helpful, in your opinion what are the very important algorithms to know as a front-end developer :)?

Comment: There aren't any very important algorithms, to be honest. It really depends on your needs. The front-end developer's job is so vast (JS, Front framework, State management, Html, Styling, Accessibility, SEO, Module bundling, etc). For a front-end beginner, I would start from the very basics with Html (Having a nice usage of the semantic is a must-have), learn a clean CSS, and pure JS. Too many devs are trying to get ahead of the game.

Comment: That's so clear Man :) I appreciate it a lot. Thank you